# Rails / Sinatra SOA architecture internal authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, soa

I'm currently implementing a Rails and sinatra based architecture and struggling with determining which kind of authentication in terms of data access i should be providing.

The services (Sinatra) should respond to the main app (Rails, using HTTParty based client) but also to API clients.

Which authentication / authorization method should i be implementing?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would advise using OAuth 2.0. And have your main app as just another API client.

Not sure on your particular use-case but why don't you look at the [Doorkeeper gem](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper)?

You can configure various permissions, etc on a per client basis so your main app can have more data-access rights than other API clients.